# rails integration testing why fixtures rather than db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, integration-testing

I'm new to testing in rails and I don't understand why or when I should use fixtures (or factory) rather than just seeding my test db and querying it to run the tests?

In many cases, it should be faster and easier to have the same data in dev and test env.

For example, if I want to test an index page, should I create 100 records via a factory or should I seed the db with 100 records?

I someone could clarify this, it would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually a deeper question of how to test efficiently, and you will find a lot of different opinions.

The reason to avoid a database in your unit tests is merely speed. Database operations are slow. It might not seem slow with one test, but if you have continuous integration going (as you should) or when you made a quick change and just want to see what happens, those delays add up. So prefer mocks to truly unit test code.

Then your own integration tests should hit an in-memory database rather than your real database--for the same reason, speed. These will be slower than your mocked tests, but still faster than hitting the real database. When you're developing, the build-test-deploy cycle needs to be as fast as possible. Note that some people call these unit tests as well. I wouldn't, but I guess it is just semantics.

These first two kinds of tests are by developers for developers.

Then the testers will hit the real database, which will be populated with test data defined by the testers and subject-matter experts. There are lots of clever ways to speed this up as well, but this will be the place where they test the integration of your code with the production-like database. If all your in-memory database tests passed and something goes wrong here, then you know it has to do with something like database configuration, vendor-specific SQL, etc. rather than something fundamentally bad. You will also get your first taste of what the performance is like.

Note that everything I've said here is a matter of debate. But hopefully it clarifies what you should consider about when to do certain things and why.

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't find this kind of answer anywhere. Just to summarize: it's all about speed... ?

Comment: Speed and efficiency in my opinion.